ошибка g++: ld returned 116 exit status
Я перерыл кучу сайтов, ничего не нашел насчет этой проблемы. Опишу проблему тут:
Любая компиляция программы появляется эта ошибка, не знаю как это исправить:
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 116 exit status

Полный код ошибки:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-14.1.0/configure --prefix=/ucrt64 --with-local-prefix=/ucrt64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 
--with-native-system-header-dir=/ucrt64/include --libexecdir=/ucrt64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,rust,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/ucrt64 --with-mpfr=/ucrt64 --with-mpc=/ucrt64 --with-isl=/ucrt64 --with-pkgversion='Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --with-boot-ldflags=-static-libstdc++ --with-stage1-ldflags=-static-libstdc++
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 14.1.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'HelloWorld.exe' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=nocona' '-dumpdir' 'HelloWorld-'
 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/ -D_REENTRANT main.cpp -quiet -dumpdir HelloWorld- -dumpbase main.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=nocona -version -o C:\Users\PROGRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cctN3fs5.s
GNU C++17 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) version 14.1.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 14.1.0, GMP version 6.3.0, MPFR version 4.2.1, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.26-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/14.1.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/14.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/14.1.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "D:/a/msys64/ucrt64/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/ucrt64/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "D:/a/msys64/ucrt64/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/14.1.0
 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/14.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include/c++/14.1.0/backward
 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/include
 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../include
 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
Compiler executable checksum: d7a8e66cf2f26a72e527b0aced6104da
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'HelloWorld.exe' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=nocona' '-dumpdir' 'HelloWorld-'
 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o C:\Users\PROGRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBaGxVD.o C:\Users\PROGRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cctN3fs5.s
COMPILER_PATH=C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'HelloWorld.exe' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=nocona' '-dumpdir' 'HelloWorld.'
 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/liblto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\PROGRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc12jeoi.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o HelloWorld.exe C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o 
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0 -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../.. C:\Users\PROGRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBaGxVD.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../lib/default-manifest.o C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/crtend.o
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 116 exit status

Сам код c++:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

У меня компилятор g++ находится в C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin. Попробовал переустановить ucrt64, не помогло 
Кто нибудь подскажите как это исправить?

¿Какой командой собираете, что вылезает такое полотно?

@user7860670 Этой командой g++ main.cpp -o HelloWorld -v

¿А команду эту вводите в среде msys ucrt64?

@user7860670 Нет, в cmd

А, ну вот и ваша проблема. Выполняйте команды в окружении msys. В меню Пуск по идее для этого уже должны быть ярлыки.

@user7860670 О сработало, спасибо)
